# Existence of Continuous Function on a Complex Region

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $\Omega = \mathbb C\backslash [-1,1]$, i.e. deleting ``the line'' only, is there a function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ such that $f$ satisfies $f(z)^2 = 1-z^2$ and is continuous on this region?

My guess is that such a function would exist, but requires a piecewise definition. A candidate solution I have been working on is $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(1-z^2)}$. The problem with this solution is having the domain, as I realize it is possible to have $1-z^2>1$, where my solution is well-defined. Is there a way to work around this or should I try something else? Thanks!

Comment: Does $f$ have to be holomorphic?

Comment: @Frank Oops, forgot to mention that, but continuous is good enough

Comment: Try defining your function first on say $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,1]$, and then arguing that it can be extended continuously to $(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Hi, can you be more specific about your construction? I'm a bit lost about why are we trying to delete the interval $(-\infty, 1]$ to construct this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the principal branch of $\log$ we can define
$\eta(w) = \sqrt{1-w}$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [1,\infty)$, and we can then define $\phi(z) = \eta({1 \over z})$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$. Note that $\phi$ is analytic.

Define $f: \mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z) = iz^2\phi(z) \phi(-z)$ and note that $f(z)^2 = 1-z^2$.